# Differences between Heracleum mantegazzianum and H. sphondylium

Tags: species-identification, botany

I have heard about the [hazards associated with Giant Hogweed](https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/827332/giant-hogweed-poisonous-plant-spotted-britain-reactions-injuries) and the trouble is when trying to identify it, it is very similar by the looks to normal hogweed.

When fully grown, there is a big difference in height with Giant Hogweed (hence the name **Giant** Hogweed, but when it is small, how can you tell the difference?

**Giant hogweed (Heracleum mantegazzianum)**
[image: Giant hogweed (Heracleum mantegazzianum)]
<sup>Image from [WikiMedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Giant_hogweed_2.JPG)</sup>

**Hogweed (Heracleum sphondylium)**
[image: Hogweed (Heracleum sphondylium)]
<sup>Image from [WikiMedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Heracleum_sphondylium_Hogweed_%E1%83%93%E1%83%98%E1%83%A7%E1%83%98.JPG)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the species can be identified by the shape of the leaves. The leaves of *H. sphondylium* are more or less flat (in one plane); the leaves of *H. manteggazianum* are more crisped and much more pointed.

Here are two pictures from the Dutch wikipedia (h. sphondylium last):
[image]
[image]